# Could not resolve maven dependencies with gradle - Host is down

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to sync my android project and it fails to download ANY dependencies.

```
 Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/2.5.1/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/2.5.1/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1.pom'.
               > Host is down
```

but if I click that link manually it downloads it fine.

I recently been using Charles Proxy, and added it in my IntelliJ preferences but now I reversed it. ...And anyway it fails even with `./gradlew build` called outside from the IDE.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but intellij decided to add proxy configuration in my

`~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file

removing it fixed the issue